# How can I know if a decompiled APK is obfuscated?

Tags: android, security, apk, obfuscation

I am checking an APK for obfuscation within it's components code, but I'm not sure if it was in fact implemented.

How can I know for sure if they are protecting their APK's code through obfuscation? As in what procedure should I follow and what elements will make me notice if they are or not? Is there a way to know just by looking at the decompiled code if ProGuard, DexGuard or some other obfuscation technique is in place?

I know obfuscating is mostly security through obscurity, this is just one of the things I'm checking.

I've decompiled the APK with both a webservice and apktool, obtaining different results, ie. for a particular folder, its subfolders appear as a,b,c in the one decompiled by apktool but appear with other names (as p00xxxx) in the folder output from the web service.

Also:

- Method and field names appear as a,ab,ac,v0,v1,etc.
- When greping for 'user','usuario','password' or 'contraseña' the only
  instances of these strings are in xml 'name' tag attributes and in
  literal strings such as "please enter your password". These
  tags ids' are in the form of: 'aXaaaaaaaa'. This seems to me like a proof of obfuscation. As posed [here](https://samsclass.info/128/proj/p10-proguard.htm) (under the 'Search for password' title).
- It seems possible to me for DexGuard to be implemented, as the
  code I've revised looks a lot like the examples portrayed [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/Hacked%20Team.git/core-android/RCSAndroid/antlibs/historic/DexGuard5.5.72/docs/examples.html#repackaging)
  ('Obfuscating Package Names')

I also read somewhere that the presence of goto instructions may  indicate obfuscation, is this right?

To sum up, I just want to know if there is a way for me to know if the APK was obfuscated, what should I do in order to check this, and what signs should I be looking for. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: methods and fields a, ab, etc. indicate either obfuscation or a very crazy developer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. So, should I assume that there's code obfuscation in place? I thought that method, fields and classes being named a,ab,etc was due to decompilation limitations and that the decompiler did that by itself to make it have sense. Could you guide me on this?

Comment: I have never heard of that, where did you read this? And why is it so important if it’s obfuscated?

Comment: It's important in the sense that if it is, that aspect of their security measures is ok, if it's not it should be pointed out so developer team can obfuscate and update the app. This being said, the reason I'm not sure if it is obfuscated is actually what I mentioned earlier, me having read the reason methods, classes and/or fields appear to be named as a,ab,v0,v1,etc to be because of some limitations in decompiling process itself. Don't quite remember where I read that, but that's the understanding I had and from it comes my confusion. So is that incorrect? I feel really puzzled now tbh.

Comment: I don’t know what decompiling method you used… but if this is a Java application, you can look at `.class` files, you can tell whether they are obfuscated because that’s when the methods name will change. Take a look at the process here: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-compilation-process

Comment: Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

First, let's begin with why is obfuscation important.
I saw a person in the comments asking this question. If we decide to build a let's say a simple game then we build it and post it in the community they can easily take our source code. Bad? Well yes , first they can exploit our code and find vulnerabilities for a hack and second its YOUR code ... So obfuscation matters.
Second, Yes, your code is obfuscated. Obfuscation varies but the idea is to make the code as less human-readable as possible. Who would understand a method named abc.c.A(d)?
The compiler, but we will not.